# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Crash

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Installed SQL Server 2012. But when launched its crashing with following message

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3  <br>
  Problem Signature 01: Ssms.exe <br>
  Problem Signature 02: 2011.110.2100.60 <br>
  Problem Signature 03: 4f35e2d9 <br>
  Problem Signature 04: PresentationCore <br>
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.34209 <br>
  Problem Signature 06: 5348b56b <br>
  Problem Signature 07: 1222 <br>
  Problem Signature 08: 16 <br>
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidCastException <br>
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 <br>
  Locale ID:    1033 <br>
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e  <br>
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 <br>
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e <br>
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 <br>
```

[Please check Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5iYS.png)

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you added that picture, it really adds to the question..

Comment: That's not SQL Server crashing, just Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rerun The SQL server installer and try what happens, if not unistall manegment and download from download center...

Comment: I tried it all. problem was solved at last only when I formatted the PC and installed it on fresh windows installation.. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is my error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: Ssms.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2011.110.5058.0
  Problem Signature 03: 537406e3
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1098.0
  Problem Signature 06: 58cf7273
  Problem Signature 07: 157f
  Problem Signature 08: 12e
  Problem Signature 09: IOIBMURHYNRXKW0ZXKYRVFN0BOYYUFOW
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

In my case, I try to run SSMS as different user.
[image]

I have 2 users (user1 as admin in PC, say user1 is not registered on PC and user2 is registered as admin on my PC)

[image]

Then, what I have tried:

- Install SQL Server 2012 SP1 --> Not Working
- Install [latest SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) --> It is working with normal user, but it is not what I expected. I can not run SSMS as user1 (no admin role)
- in the Last, I add user which I use to run SSMS and give role as administrator, then it is work.

Then my suggestion is, you must check `user role` at control panel, you must try one by one if you do not want use `Administrator role`. At my case, I am just add role administrator at the user, then everything is going well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any add-ons installed from 3rd party for SQL Server. If yes,  uninstall them and again open SQL Server Management Studio. My issue got resolved when I uninstalled 3rd party software "Supratimas for SQL Server".

I had tried uninstall, re-install. Going from SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2014 to 2012. But nothing worked for me.